# Virus infected file Decompilation

Tags: decompiling, virus

I have an executable file (program.exe) That is virus infected.

Is there any possible way to decompile it or remove the virus? I don't need to use the program too much, but I'm really interested in how it works.

The threat name is : Suspicious.Cloud.2 . Is it a threat if I use linux too?

Comment: don't you have a backup?

Comment: and no - it will not affect your linux system.

Comment: Decompiling and removing the virus are two *completely* different tasks.

Comment: @DanielA.White - it's possible running the file under wine would still result in bad things happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to remove the virus, but depending on the platform there are "decompilers" available on the market, but whether this gives you anything useful is another matter. Some will only reverse compile the executable into base assembler for the target processor and of course it will depend on whether the virus code was run through some form of variable/procedure hiding before hand.

On the other hand there have been a number of false positives reported, particularly with Norton for this virus. So worth checking there first.